# how to fetch xml data from ascx page url?

Tags: .net

i have the url for ascx page and i want to fetch the xml data from that page using the page url...is it possible in .net

Comment: Wait. You have the URL for an **ascx** page?

Comment: http://localhost:63172/GolfPlatze/GolfPlatze_Service.asmx?op=GetClubList

Comment: That looks more like an **asmx** (web service) URL?

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET, the `.ascx` file extension is used for files containing markup for user controls, not pages. A user control is a reusable "block" of other controls and logic, which can be embedded in one of more pages throughout your web application.

A user control does not have its own URL. Even though the file sits below the project folder in the file system it does not respond (well) to HTTP requests made for domain + path to `.ascx` file. The user control can only be rendered as part of a page.

If you want to have a URL that gets the content rendered by a user control and nothing else, consider making a new `.aspx` page in your project with only the control declaration.